# How do I align items in a <details>

Tags: html, css

I want to have a details that has a width of 100% and that aligns it's items to the right.

I have tried:

```
details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

HTML:

```
<details>
  <summary>example</summary>

  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
</details>
```

The problem is, that the items are 100% wide and don't get aligned to the right.

Comment: can you add html code also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `text-align` CSS property, instead of `flex`:

```
details {
   text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: This works, but why does the flex stuff not work? Isn't this kinda a hacky solution?

Comment: I don’t know exactly, I think it’s because `details` has a width of 100%.

Answer (score 2):

try to use `justify-content:space-between` instead of `align-item:flex-end`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```css
details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
summary ~ div {
  text-align:right;
}}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>example</summary>

  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
</details>
```